# php if statement not executing even though true

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to compare two passwords to make sure they match and redirect if not using php. I have written this code, but the code within the if statement does not execute even if the passwords dont match.

```
<?php 
include 'includes/dbcnx.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if($password != $pass2)
    header('Location: register_form.php');
if(strlen($username)>30)
    header('Location: register_form.php?error=1&usrlen=1');

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256',$salt.$hash);
mysql_select_db("sealion");
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt, email)
        VALUES ('$username','$hash','$salt','$email');";
mysql_query($query);
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: How did you confirm it's not executing that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code *does* execute, but a `header()` will not stop the rest of the code being executed on it's own:

```
if($password != $pass2)
{
    header('Location: register_form.php');
    exit;
}
```

On that note, your code might be easier to read if you put the entire suite of operations inside the conditional statement.

```
if($password != $pass2)
{
    header('Location: register_form.php');
}
else if(strlen($username)>30)
{
    header('Location: register_form.php?error=1&usrlen=1');
}
else
{
    // Do your updates here...
}
```

This would make your code easier to read by the next chap (or if you come back to in in six months time) - and would also make it impossible for multiple actions to happen.

Comment: Yeah I can see that would be a more elegant way of doing it, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

After the `header` redirect command you need to `exit;` otherwise the code just continues to run, giving duplicate header commands - the last one you send is the one that acts.

Comment: Ah great, that sorted it! I always thought the header command exited the code itself... doh! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You change the `Location` header again at the end of your script:

```
if(strlen($username)>30)
    header('Location: register_form.php?error=1&usrlen=1');
/* ... */
header('Location: index.php');
```

My guess is the `if` block is executing properly, but calling the `header()` function a second time is changing the header. Try using an `if-else` instead:

```
if(strlen($username)>30) {
    header('Location: register_form.php?error=1&usrlen=1');
}
else {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $salt = createSalt();
    $hash = hash('sha256',$salt.$hash);
    mysql_select_db("sealion");
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt, email)
            VALUES ('$username','$hash','$salt','$email');";
    mysql_query($query);
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```